Socket _bind: can't assign requested address
I try to Access to the server this message appears (socket _bind: can't assign requested address

please read [ask] then [edit] your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
